# Plugins to increase security of Chrome?

Tags: web-browser, audit, chrome, browser-extensions, plugins

What plugins are there for Chrome, that would increase security while browsing the web?

For Firefox I have used NoScript, Flashblock, and AdBlock Plus, are there equivalents to these plugins for Chrome?

Several plugins I have heard about are uMatrix and uBlock.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the place for this question. Maybe refer to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) but...

I use [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en). It is a highly customizable tool for ad blocking, malicious site blocking and much more. It allows black listing and white listing of domains and uses public lists of malicious domains to block.

Comment: That is good to know.  Does it handle JavaScript, where you can enable only one JavaScript site at a time?  Thank you.

Comment: @Smiith From what I understand from the documentation, it is possible through the advanced settings. But I'm not sure how it is implemented. Give it a shot.